# Problem in create my first network on Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm tring to build my first network on fabric
I follow these tutorials:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#hyperledger-fabric-sdks (go sdk)

but, I am stuck in this doc:
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html
specific in the command (`fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw`)

I can't find -b option,
my target is to start my first network by following this link (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) 
so I want to know if the sequence of my steps is right or not and how can fix my error?

Comment: Check the version of the docs you're following and the version of fabric you're using,  Update the question if they match and the problem still remains.

Comment: there is a second way to start the server https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#start-server-via-docker have you tried this?